# Need a Web Part for a Page to display a document library for selected subsite

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part

In SharePoint Foundation 2010, I have a Site > Subsite structure in which all Subsites were created with a template, and house the exact same folder structure.  What I would like to do is create a top-level "Portal Page" belonging to the Parent Site that has web parts that list the contents of a particular Document Library for a site that is selected by the user.  So, consider:

ParentSite

- SubsiteA (has Accounts Document Library)
- SubsiteB (has Accounts Document Library)
- SubsiteC (has Accounts Document Library)

Each Subsite has the same document libraries.  On the ParentSite's default page, i want to display a "master view" of the document library, but limit it to see the library of the site they have selected.  So maybe, if I go to

```
http://mysite/ParentSite/SitePages/Home.aspx?Subsite=SubsiteA
```

...then my Portal Page will display a view of the Accounts Document Library belonging to SubsiteA.  If I have SubsiteB in the query string, display a view of the Accounts Document Library in SubsiteB (and so on).  Do I need a custom web part for this?  Can this be accomplished in SharePoint Designer?  I definitely don't see this as a possibility in the UI.

Comment: Yeah... y'all don't know how to do it.  Because it's SharePoint... and SharePoint stinks.  Go ahead, admit it. ;)

Comment: Content By Query Webpart can help you in this. But for that you need to activate the Publishing feature.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what that means lol.  But, I'm sure I can Google all that and figure it out.  Thanks!